# Angular CLI - How to have the version information after building for prod?

Tags: angular, build, version

I would like to access the version information present in package.json from the files generated with ng build --prod. 
I'm already displaying the version in the title of my app but I need to run a script which will retrieve the version post-build.

How can I have this version information post-build ? Or is it possible to ask to generate a file version.txt during the build ?

Comment: You can't retrieve the information post-build, but you can build the app with the version. Would that suit you ?

Comment: I want a way to know the version, written in package.json, post-build

Comment: I just told you you can't. But you can build with the app with the version in it. That's exactly the same, but if you don't want, then so be it.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand what you mean by the app with the version in it.

Comment: The version will be a avariable in your `environment.ts` file, meaning you can access it from whatever component you desire. `The version in it` simply meant your bundled application with the version in the bundle (because `package.json` isn't bundled).

Answer (score 1):

Well,

You can write a script to manage this.

Something like this:
https://medium.com/@amcdnl/version-stamping-your-app-with-the-angular-cli-d563284bb94d